# Displaying Data Upon Data Retrieval - Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am able to save data into my database using the code below. When the user clicks on the checkbox, the name of the item is displayed and stored in the database. But my problem now is, when I am editing the stored data, I am able to retrieve the items which were checked (the items selected and saved previously)  but the JS for appending code doesn't run.

When I uncheck and check it again, it works normally.

When editing, the items saved in the database are checked but the JS part of the code which displays the name of the item selected doesn't run. Why is that happening?

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name" class="col-lg-1 control-label"> Name</label>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" id="name" value="{!!$item->products['name']!!}" placeholder="  Name" name="name" required>
  </div>
</div>
<input onclick="return data(this)" data-food="{{$product->toJson()}}" type="checkbox" id="{!! $product->id !!}" name="{!! $product->name !!}" 
value="{!! $product->price !!}"  @foreach ($product->emps as $deliver)   @if($product->id == $deliver->id) checked @endif @endforeach  />
```

**JS**

```
function data(item)
{ 
  var ad = JSON.parse(item.dataset.stuff);

  if(item.checked == true)  {
    $('.container').append(
    '<div class="shipment_container" > '+ 
    '<p  class="name" >'+ad.name+'</p>'+
    '</div>');
  }
  else {
    $(".container.shipment_container [data-id=" + ad.id + "]").parent().remove();
  }
}
```

**update**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


    function data(item)
    { 
      var ad = JSON.parse(item.dataset.stuff);

      if(item.checked == true)  {
        $('.container').append(
        '<div class="shipment_container" > '+ 
        '<p  class="name" >'+ad.name+'</p>'+
        '</div>');
      }
      else {
        $(".container.shipment_container [data-id=" + ad.id + "]").parent().remove();
      }
    }



});
```

Comment: Grab the `<input>` element and pass it to the `data()` function on [document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: @Camilo please look at my update but it is still not working

Comment: can you show generated html code from blade ?

Comment: 1.check whether `data` function is called when you click the check box(use a alert box)
2. if its working check whether container is exist the time you call the function `alert($('.container').length)`

Comment: @SupunFictionPraneeth  yes data function is called when you click

Comment: Check wether container exit too

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `data()` only when the checkbox is clicked but on the edit screen you need to call it on load and pass the parameter manually.

Something like this:

```
function data(item)
{ 
  if(item.checked == true)  {
    // Do something if the item was chacked
  }
  else {
    // Do something else if it wasn't
  }
}

$( document ).ready(function() {

  var input = document.querySelector('input#{!! $product->id !!}');

  data(input);
});
```

Comment: Nothing happens even with the `document` ready function. Besides there are a lot of `inputs` in the code so how can i specify in this line `var input =document.querySelector('input');`

Comment: You should add an ID or a proper class to your input and modify the `querySelector()`. What is the value of `ad` when you call `data(input)`?

Comment: Yes i have an id for the that particular input.

Comment: I don't see any `id` attribute on your example.

Comment: there is id  attribute in this `input` <input onclick="return data(this)" data-food="{{$product->toJson()}}" type="checkbox" id="{!! $product->id !!}" name="{!! $product->name !!}"

Comment: document.ready will only run when the checkbox is clicked according to your code.

Comment: Okay i have the document.ready running but i still cant fetch the item checked onto the container.

Comment: What parameter are you passing to the query selector?